# why itempipeline is not working in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am writing a crawler using scrapy to find out all the department webpages of a university. 
But it seems my pipeline is not working. Does anyone know why? 
Here is the code for my spider:

```
class Univ2deptemorySpider(Spider):
    name = 'univ2deptEmory'

    def __init__(self, url='http://www.emory.edu/', **kw):
        super(Univ2deptemorySpider,self).__init__(**kw)
        self.url = url
        self.allowed_domains = [re.sub(r'^www\.', '', urlparse(url).hostname)]

    def start_requests(self):
        return [Request(self.url, callback=self.find_all_url, dont_filter=False)]

    def find_all_url(self,response):
        if self.check_dept(response):
            self.parse_dept(response)

        links = LinkExtractor().extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            if len(link.url) < 50:
                yield Request(link.url, callback = self.find_all_url, dont_filter=False)

    def parse_dept(self, response):
        dept = deptItem()
        #did some extraction            
        return dept

    def check_dept(self,response):
        #check whether the given page is a department webpage, if yes, return True, otherwise False
```

And here is the code for pipeline:

```
class deptPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
    #connect to a sqlite database 


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        cur = self.conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('select * from department where deptName=(?)',(item['deptName'],))
        res = cur.fetchall()
        if not (len(res) > 0):
            cur.execute('insert into department(deptName, url, description, photo) values (?,?,?,?) ', (item["deptName"], item['url'], item['description'], item['photo']))
            self.conn.commit()
```

From the log info, I can see that the `__init__` in pipeline works fine, but the `process_item` is never called.

Setting related to item pipeline:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'advisor.pipelines.deptPipeline': 300}
```

advisor is the name for project.

EDIT1: the item pipeline works before I modify my spider code so I guess the problem might come from spider. And I added some logging in both `parse_dept`, and `process_item`, it seems everything is executed in `parse_dept` before return, while nothing is executed in `process_item`.

Comment: By the way, when I use return dept and yield, it produces different results, why is that?

Comment: Please show your `ITEM_PIPELINES` setting. Also, are you sure the code of your pipeline is indented properly?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just check indentation, it looks OK, and I added a log command at the beginning of 'process_item', it is never executed. @alecxe

Comment: By the way, the item pipeline works before I modify the spider code, and after some searches, I think the problem might come from my spider code, but I just don't know what's wrong with it.